# Changing the Y axis unit in Chartjs

Tags: chart.js

I feel like this is an underdocumented feature, but I admit it's far more likely that I am undergoogling it.

I have a charjs object:

```
<body>
    <div id="container" style="width: 75%;">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script>
    weekdays=["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thurday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday"]
    var d=new Date()
        var MONTHS = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

        var randomScalingFactor = function() {
            return (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1.0 : 0) * Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
        };

        var barChartData = {
           labels: [weekdays[d.getDay()], weekdays[d.getDay()-6], weekdays[d.getDay()-5], weekdays[d.getDay()-4], weekdays[d.getDay()-3], weekdays[d.getDay()-2],weekdays[d.getDay()-1]    ],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Logged Time',
                backgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                data: sessions
            }
            ]

        };

        window.onload = function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: barChartData,
                options: {
                    // Elements options apply to all of the options unless overridden in a dataset
                    // In this case, we are setting the border of each bar to be 2px wide and green
                    elements: {
                        rectangle: {
                            borderWidth: 2,
                            borderColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
                            borderSkipped: 'bottom'
                        }
                    },
                    responsive: true,
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Vision Logged Hours'
                    }
                }
            });

        };




    </script>
```

that looks like this:

[image]

My problem is that the y-axis is in minutes and I want it in hours. I'm a little lost about the feature set - is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a simple hand-made function :

```
function minutesToHours(minutes) {
    var hour = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    minutes = minutes % 60;
    return ((hour < 10) ? "0"+hour : hour) + ":" + ((minutes < 10) ? "0"+minutes : minutes);
}
```

You can then use the `userCallback` property of the yAxes ticks like this :

```
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                userCallback: function(item) {
                    return minutesToHours(item);
                },
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

---

You can see a working example [on this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/22b37xvb/), and here is its result :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to official documentation, [creating custom tick formats](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats), just simply use a callback function.

```js
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return '$' + value;
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I've discovered that you can add the '$' sign after the value by simply swapping it with the value, like {return value + '$';}. I've actually used this for percentage sign (%).